# How can I print a SharePoint list without all the chrome?

Tags: list, printing

Is there a way to print the list you are looking at without all the browser chrome? I have seen  List Print by Bamboo Solutions which does something similar.

Answer (score 6):

As another quick, out of the box idea for a solution, add `IsDlg=1` to the URL of your desired List view. It'll use a minimalist masterpage designed for use in Dialogs, but also includes a condensed view of the ribbon.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to print documents too then there is nothing out of the box, you will probably be limited to doing something custom or getting a third party solution.  I found [this](http://spprintlist.codeplex.com/) on codeplex but it only works for 2007.  You might be able to use it as a base for a 2010 version though?

If it's just list data then you can export it to Excel and print from there.

Answer (score 2):

We've used [this](http://www.spelements.com/spprint/) in 2007, I don't see any mention of an upgrade yet.  For web part pages, [Christophe](http://pathtosharepoint.com/default.aspx) has a slick print option in his [easy tabs](http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx) script.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Export the list or library to Excel.
2. Create a data connection to the list or library so that the workbook automatically syncs with list updates when opened.
3. Format the workbook for printing.
4. Save the workbook to SharePoint for users.

For step-by-step instructions view my post at https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2015/03/28/print-live-list-or-library-data-from-excel-workbooks-using-data-connections/.

Answer (score 0):

About exporting it to Excel Sheet and then print it or build a custom page using sharepoint designer and then create a print view there

Comment: Creating a page in SharePoint Designer will still include the masterpage and the chrome that comes with it.